# Underlining a string using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

So I am writing to a pdf through java using iText.  I want to have a blank signature and date spaces underlined.  Everything I read said to do it like so:

```
    Chunk sigUnderline = new Chunk("                                            ");
        sigUnderline.setUnderline(0.2f, -2f);
    Chunk dateUnderline = new Chunk("                       ");  
        dateUnderline.setUnderline(0.2f, -2f);

    verificationList.open();
    verificationList.add(new Paragraph("Authorized Signature: " + sigUnderline + "Date: " + dateUnderline));

    verificationList.close();
```

So basically I am trying to underline blank strings to create these "fields".  I have also tried to put text in the string(s), and the underlining still doesnt work.  Is there something I am missing, any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are concatenating String with Chunk objects. Add the underlines as Chunk's

```
    Chunk sigUnderline = new Chunk("                                            ");
    sigUnderline.setUnderline(0.1f, -2f);
    Chunk dateUnderline = new Chunk("                       ");
    dateUnderline.setUnderline(0.1f, -2f);

    Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Authorized Signature: ");
    para.add(sigUnderline);
    para.add(new Chunk(" Date: "));
    para.add(dateUnderline);

    document.add(para);
```

Comment: Great!  This works, rookie mistake, first time creating a pdf.  Thank You!