# Underline some part of text in pdf - java

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

i have predefined text which needs to be displayed on pdf while, but some part of the text should be marked underline.

```
paragraph.add(new Chunk("text_underline on pdf", f11).UNDERLINE);
```

I used `chunk.underline` but that underlines entire paragraph. I want to underline only one word within the paragraph. please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the paragraph object itself. Add two chunk objects, one to underline and one for normal

Refer [Underlining a string using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703723/underlining-a-string-using-itext)